# Road Lane Detection: How to tell dashed lanes apart from solid lanes?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

All of the tutorials I located regarding detecting lanes never differentiated between dashed lanes and solid lanes. Clearly, in a real self-driving car, this would be a major issue! How do self-driving cars tell dashed lanes apart from solid lanes? I found this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/306305796_Road_Lane_Detection_by_Discriminating_Dashed_and_Solid_Road_Lanes_Using_a_Visible_Light_Camera_Sensor but it doesn't have any code. Could somebody locate code for this purpose?

Comment: Try googling a little more: https://paperswithcode.com/task/lane-detection

Comment: Thanks for the link! I skimmed through some of those papers, but they don't tell the dashed lanes apart from solid lanes.